# Does s4cmd support signature version 4 because i am unable to upload files to s3 bucket (LONDON)

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files to s3 bucket(LONDON) i.e. eu-west-2. S4cmd is not working.

s4cmd put /home/username/Documents/file-1.json s3://[BUCKETNAME]/file-1.json

error when i run this command is  : -

```
[Exception] An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request
[Thread Failure] An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request
```

S3cmd works but it is slow. s4cmd works for US standard region but for London region it is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes i have been using aws cli commands but the requirement that we have is to upload big files like 37Gb - 50Gb in less than 3 minutes. s4cmd helps in achieving that.

Comment: The `aws s3 cp` command in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) uses multi-part upload to fully utilize available bandwidth. Have you found it to be slower? And, by the way, transferring 50GB in 3 minutes will require a 2000 MBps connection, which is 1000 x T1 lines.

Comment: Hi John, Aws CLI is faster. Have applied it on application. You can post your answer in answer section so that i can accept your answer. Thanks,Diptendu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `aws s3 cp` command in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) uses multi-part upload to fully utilize available bandwidth, so it should give you pretty much the best speed possible.